# Autocomplete on dynamic textbox using jquery+autocomplete plugin

Tags: jquery, textbox, autocomplete

I am using a form which has dynamic textboxes I want autocomplete functionality to be implemented on them and I am using [Autocomplete Plugin](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-autocomplete/) and I want to bind them using live().

Can anyone help me out on how to implement it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "live()" facility is for event handling, not for initializing plugins. When you add your text inputs, you'll have to also call the autocomplete initialization at that time.